# How to fix offset shift in GestureDetector.onScaleUpdate when lifting the finger after drag on iOS device?

Tags: ios, flutter, gesturedetector

When I finish dragging a `Positioned` widget I notice that there's a small shift in the final position when I lift the finger off the screen on the iOS device (iOS 14.6). This behaviour also present in the iOS emulator but very visible on the physical device:

[image: iOS device GestureDetector screen recording]

– notice the slight position shift after the red cube stops moving.

Demo's source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 
class GestureDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const GestureDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 
  @override
  GestureDemoState createState() => GestureDemoState();
}
 
class GestureDemoState extends State<GestureDemo> {
 
  late Offset _startingFocalPoint;
 
  late Offset _previousOffset;
  Offset _offset = Offset.zero;
 
  late double _previousZoom;
  double _zoom = 1.0;
 
  final containerSize = Size(100, 100);
 
  void _handleScaleStart(ScaleStartDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      _startingFocalPoint = details.focalPoint;
      _previousOffset = _offset;
      _previousZoom = _zoom;
    });
  }
 
  void _handleScaleUpdate(ScaleUpdateDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      _zoom = _previousZoom * details.scale;
 
      // Ensure that item under the focal point stays in the same place despite zooming
      final Offset normalizedOffset = (_startingFocalPoint - _previousOffset) / _previousZoom;
      _offset = details.focalPoint - normalizedOffset * _zoom;
    });
  }
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
          top: _offset.dy,
          left: _offset.dx,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onScaleStart: _handleScaleStart,
            onScaleUpdate:_handleScaleUpdate,
 
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              width: containerSize.width * _zoom,
              height: containerSize.height * _zoom,
            ),
          )
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
 
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData.dark(),
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Gestures Demo')),
      body: const GestureDemo(),
    ),
  ));
}
```

This is a simplified version of the official [widget gestures example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/157bc92d4a844f2284a505e3f460eeb3882be475/examples/layers/widgets/gestures.dart) from Flutter.

When I log `ScaleUpdateDetails`, I see that the last `details` have a small shift

```
ScaleUpdateDetails(focalPoint: Offset(174.0, 260.5), localFocalPoint: Offset(28.5, 73.0), scale: 1.0, horizontalScale: 1.0, verticalScale: 1.0, rotation: 0.0, pointerCount: 1)
ScaleUpdateDetails(focalPoint: Offset(174.0, 260.0), localFocalPoint: Offset(28.5, 72.5), scale: 1.0, horizontalScale: 1.0, verticalScale: 1.0, rotation: 0.0, pointerCount: 1)
ScaleUpdateDetails(focalPoint: Offset(173.0, 258.0), localFocalPoint: Offset(27.5, 70.5), scale: 1.0, horizontalScale: 1.0, verticalScale: 1.0, rotation: 0.0, pointerCount: 1)
```

How to remove this position shift?

Comment: @pskink could you please elaborate why would it work better if it's a wrapper of a GestureDetector?

Comment: @pskink could you please provide more details? I'm sorry otherwise it looks like a spam link to a wrapper library.